# Is this the correct way to use semicolon and commas?

Tags: commas, semicolons

Her appearance looked effortless; a shift dress with a classic sweater, dainty jewelry, and mid-heel pumps.

Comment: No: not a semicolon but rather a colon or em dash is called for there.

Answer (score 3):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such you should consult your manual of style.  I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which recommends  that when semicolons are used, they should separate clauses (or lists of items that themselves require commas). What you have following your semicolon is not a clause.  The recommended usage would be

> Her appearance looked effortless; a shift dress with a classic
>   sweater, dainty jewelry, and mid-heel pumps made up her wardrobe.

You may use a dash to indicate that the following items are an expansion, here of her appearance:

> Her appearance looked effortless—a shift dress with a classic
>   sweater, dainty jewelry, and mid-heel pumps.

You may use a colon to indicate that the following items are an "illustration or amplification," here of effortless couture:

> Her appearance looked effortless:  a shift dress with a classic
>   sweater, dainty jewelry, and mid-heel pumps.